# junit тест с использованием параметризованных значений

Tags: java, junit

Задача протестировать метод setVolume. При передачи значений в качестве аргумента setVolume отдельно, тест проходит. Но при параметризировании получаю исключение (org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ParameterResolutionException: No ParameterResolver registered for parameter [int arg0])

```
@RunWith(JUnitParamsRunner.class)
public class SoundClipBaseTest {
    public Object[] getvalidVolume() { return $(0,34,100); }
    ISoundClipBase soundClipBase;
    private String validPath = "/res/audio/ValidPath.wav";

    @BeforeEach
    public void setUp(){
        soundClipBase = new SoundClipBase(validPath);
    }

    @Test
    @Parameters(method = "getvalidVolume")
    public void setVolume_SetValidVolume_GetSameValue(int soundValue){
        /// Arrange

        /// Act
        soundClipBase.setVolume(soundValue);

        /// Assert
        Assertions.assertThat(soundClipBase.getVolume())
                .isEqualTo(soundValue);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Метод `getvalidVolume()` должен возвращать массив массивов. Попробуйте так:

```
public Object[] getvalidVolume() { return $( $(0), $(34), $(100) ); }
```

Массив массивов нужен для того, чтобы определять параметры на каждый тесткейс в случае, если у вас несколько параметров:

```
public Object[] getAddCases() { return $( $(0, 1, 1), $(-1, 1, 0) ); }

@Parameters(method = "getAddCases")
public void testCalculatorAdd(int a, int b, int result)
```